# preg-split regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am having the input string of

> Aspen,Colorado-USA

I want to split it by using preg-split

I want this output:

> Array ( [0] => Aspen [1] => Colorado [2] => USA )

I have used like this

```
$input=Aspen,Colorado-USA;
$out=preg_split( "%[^a-zA-Z\s]%",$input);
```

is it correct? I want to know efficient way to do this.

Comment: Even regex is not clever enough to modify the content. Do you mean you want the output `Array ( [0] => Aspen [1] => Colorado [2] => USA )`?

Comment: Also, I assume `$input` is in fact a string?

Comment: Is the input data always in the form `City`,`State`-`Country`?  Do you need to support *any* country, or do you have a specific list?  And are there any other locations that need to be converted to Las Vegas, or is it only Aspen Colorado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to turn Aspen into Las Vegas, you might want to split on `,` and `-`:

```
$out= preg_split('/[,-]/', $input);
```

However, this assumes that neither commas nor dashes will occur in your city/state names.

Comment: If there is a chance, that there might be dashes in state-city name, you can always make a DB with all possible states and city names ( probably downloadable from internet ) and check on those names when splitting.

Comment: ...or create a rule, for example to only split on the last dash in the string. But then again, you would fail for strings like `"Sarajevo, Sarajevski Kanton-Bosnia-Herzegovina"`...